# How to set my own upload size of attachment?

Tags: php, attachment

I want to set on this PHP code my own size limit of attachment.
I've tried lot of codes but anything isn't working.

Can u help me with it? What working code should I use there?
I want to set maximum size to 2MB, and there should be message ,,Sorry, this attachment is too big (or sth else - it's for check that it's working)".

And how to definite types to attach? For example I want only PNG and JPG to upload. How to do that on my code? And there should be message too, for example - ,,Sorry, you can only attach PNG and JPG files."

***NOTE! EVERYTHING IS WORKING RIGHT. I ONLY WANT TO CHANGE UPLOAD SIZE AND MAKE PNG AND JPG FILES :) THANKS!***

**Here is my PHP code:**

```
<?php
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

if(!empty($_POST["send"])) {
require_once ('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;

$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->Username = "wlasciciel@rubinmc.pl";
$mail->Password = "XXXXXXXXX";

$mail->Mailer = "smtp";

if (isset($_POST["userEmail"])) {
    $userEmail = $_POST["userEmail"];
}
if (isset($_POST["userName"])) {
    $userName = $_POST["userName"];
}
if (isset($_POST["subject"])) {
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
}
if (isset($_POST["userMessage"])) {
    $message = $_POST["userMessage"];
}
if (isset($_POST["NickCheatera"])) {
    $NickCheatera = $_POST["NickCheatera"];
}
$mail->SetFrom('wlasciciel@rubinmc.pl', $userName);
$mail->AddReplyTo($userEmail, $userName);
$mail->AddAddress("wlasciciel@rubinmc.pl"); // set recipient email address

$mail->Subject = 'Zgloszenie';
$mail->Body    = join('', array(
'Wiadomosc od: ',
$_POST['userName'],
'<br/>',
'E-mail: ',
$_POST['userEmail'],
'<br/>',
'Nick cheatera: ',
$_POST['NickCheatera'],
'<br/>',
'Powod: ',
$_POST['subject'],
'<br/>',
'Dodatkowe informacje: ',
'<br/>',
$_POST['userMessage'],
'<br/>'
));
$mail->WordWrap = 80;

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'serwer2092488.home.pl';

if (! empty($_FILES['attachment'])) {
    $count = count($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
    if ($count > 0) {
        // Attaching multiple files with the email
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i ++) {
            if (! empty($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])) {

                $tempFileName = $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                $fileName = $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i];
                $mail->AddAttachment($tempFileName, $fileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
if (! $mail->Send()) {
    $message = "Wystąpił problem podczas wysyłania e-maila. Spróbuj ponownie.";
    $type = "error";
} else {
    $message = "Dziękujemy za zgłoszenie! Odpowiemy do 24 godzin.";
    $type = "success";
}
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<?php
require_once "mail-sending-script.php";
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>RubinMC - zgłoś cheatera</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var valid = true;

        $(".info").html("");
        var userName = document.forms["mailForm"]["userName"].value;
        var userEmail = document.forms["mailForm"]["userEmail"].value;
        var NickCheatera = document.forms["mailForm"]["NickCheatera"].value;
        var subject = document.forms["mailForm"]["subject"].value;
        var userMessage = document.forms["mailForm"]["userMessage"].value;

        if (userName == "") {
            $("#userName-info").html("(To pole jest wymagane.)");
            $("#userName").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
            valid = false;
        }
        if (userEmail == "") {
            $("#userEmail-info").html("(To pole jest wymagane.)");
            $("#userEmail").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
            valid = false;
        }
        if (!userEmail.match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/))
        {
            $("#userEmail-info").html("(Zły format e-maila.)");
            $("#userEmail").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
            valid = false;
        }
        if (NickCheatera == "") {
            $("#NickCheatera-info").html("(To pole jest wymagane.)");
            $("#NickCheatera").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
            valid = false;
        }
        if (subject == "") {
            $("#subject-info").html("(To pole jest wymagane.)");
            $("#subject").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
            valid = false;
        }
        if (userMessage == "") {
            $("#userMessage-info").html("(To pole jest wymagane.)");
            $("#userMessage").css('background-color', '#FFFFDF');
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1 style="text-align: center">Zgłoś cheatera</h1>

<div class="attachment-form-container">
    <form name="mailForm" id="mailForm" method="post" action=""
        enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate()">

        <div class="input-row">
            <label style="padding-top: 20px;">Nick</label> <span
                id="userName-info" class="info"></span><br /> <input
                type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Wpisz swój nick..." name="userName"
                id="userName" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-row">
            <label>E-mail</label> <span id="userEmail-info"
                class="info"></span><br /> <input type="text"
                class="input-field" name="userEmail" placeholder="Wpisz adres e-mail..." 
id="userEmail" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-row">
            <label>Nick cheatera</label> <span id="NickCheatera-info"
                class="info"></span><br /> <input type="text"
                class="input-field" name="NickCheatera" placeholder="Wpisz nick cheatera..." 
id="NickCheatera" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-row">
            <label for="subject">Powód</label>
            <select id="subject" name="subject" class="input-field">
            <option disabled selected>Wybierz powód</option>
            <option id="Spam">Spam</option>
            <option id="X-Ray">X-Ray</option>
            <option value="Sales3">Sales2</option>
            </select>   
        </div>
        <div class="input-row">
            <label>Dodatkowe informacje</label> <span id="userMessage-info"
                class="info"></span><br />
            <textarea name="userMessage" id="userMessage"
                class="input-field" id="userMessage" placeholder="Wpisz dodatkowe informacje..." 
cols="60"
                rows="6"></textarea><br />
            <label>Dodaj załącznik</label>
        </div>
        <div class="attachment-row">
            <input type="file" class="input-field"
                name="attachment[]">

        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="send" style="position: relative; left: 210px" class="btn- 
  submit"
                value="Wyślij" />

            <div id="statusMessage"> 
                    <?php
                    if (! empty($message)) {
                        ?>
                        <p class='<?php echo $type; ?>Message'><?php echo $message; ?></p>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var inputPreview = $(".input-preview"),
  input = $(".input");

TweenMax.set(input, {
scale: 1.2,
alpha: 0
});

inputPreview.on("click", function(){

var that = $(this);

that.toggleClass("active");

if(that.hasClass("active")){

  TweenMax.staggerTo(input, 1.25, {
    scale: 1,
    alpha: 1,
    ease: Elastic.easeOut
  }, .1);   
}
else {
  TweenMax.staggerTo(input, 1, {
    scale: 1.2,
    alpha: 0,
    ease: Elastic.easeOut
  }, .1);
}
});

input.on("click", function() {

var tlInput = new TimelineMax({
  onComplete: done
});

var that = $(this),
  siblings = that.siblings(".input"),
  data = that.data("val"),
  top = that.css("top");

siblings.removeClass("active");

tlInput.to(siblings, .25, {
    alpha: 0
  })
  .to(that, .25, {
    scale: 1.2
  })
  .to(that, .25, {
    top: 0,
  })
  .set(inputPreview, {
    display: "none"
  })
  .to(that, .25, {
    scale: 1,
  })
  .to(that, .5, {
    backgroundColor: "#1D77EF"
  })
  .set(inputPreview, {
    text: data,
    display: "block"
  })
  .to(that, .25, {
    alpha: 0
  })

function done() {
  inputPreview.removeClass("active");
  that.css("top", top).addClass("active");

  TweenMax.set(input, {
    scale: 1.2,
    alpha: 0,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  });
}

});

// copy
balapaCop("Select Input Interaction", "rgba(255,255,255,.5)");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php check `$_FILES["attachment"]["size"]` and `$_FILES["attachment"]["type"]` maybe?

Comment: I'll add that it greatly depennd on what result you desire. You can change it globally by changing [upload-max-size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) inside php.ini, or you could change it for one script by using [ini_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

And that's just two easiest ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing upload_max_filesize in php.ini.

Comment: It works, but how to make a message that file is too big for example?